# Hide some elements in the footer using css

Tags: css, hide, element, footer

I need some help hiding some elements of the footer of my page, I am using a child theme and I have copied the footer.php file from the Main theme folder to my child theme folder.
I have tried to modify the code but it didn't work.

Basically this is my website. [www.hodst.com](http://www.hodst.com)

In the footer section on the left bottom I want to hide all the Social icons and links.
And I would like the copyrights, terms & conditions and privacy policy to be aligned either in a single line or each on a seperate line but properly aligned.

I tried to align the copyrights section in a single line but i think the width of the container is not letting it happen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at CSS grids https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp. With justify-items, column-gap (or row gap), grid-auto-flow. Try to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you want specific advices, your css has a lot of problems to fix.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and sharing the links. I have managed to modify the footer elements and align them in a single line and removing the bits i didn't want.
I used the inspector and figured out how to hide classes using the customize css option in wordpress.
However i am curious to know you mentioned my css has a lot of problems. Please can you mention some here , or should i create another post for that ?